# Print exactly next 5 lines after string in Java

Tags: java, string

I've got this code which prints out a line in the file that contains "(1)". However, now I want to be able to print out the next 5 lines below it. How would I achieve that?

```
File file =new File("./question.txt");
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            String line=in.nextLine();
            if(line.contains("(1)"))
                System.out.println(line);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {


    }
```

Comment: You know how to read a line, you know how to print a line... Can't you do this 5 times ?

Comment: what made you think you can't do it?

Comment: make a counter variable increase inside if condition. check in loop if that is >5 then break the loop

Comment: Instead of removing the question, post an answer indicating what did you do to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print out any matching line plus the next five, it's a simple matter of changing how you detect whether to print a line:

- Initially set a counter to zero.
- For every line in the file:

  - If line matches, set a counter to six.
  - If the counter is greater than zero, print that line and decrement the counter.

The pseudo-code (though not *too* far removed from Java) would be along the lines of:

```
linesLeft = 0
while in.hasNext():
    line=in.nextLine()
    if line.contains("(1)"):
        linesLeft = 6
    if linesLeft > 0:
        println (line)
        linesleft--
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this shoud works:

```
File file =new File("./question.txt");
Scanner in = null;
try {
    in = new Scanner(file);
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        String line=in.nextLine();
        if(line.contains("(1)")){
            for(int a=0;in.hasNextLine() && a<5;a++){
                System.out.println(line);
                line=in.nextLine();
            }
            return;
        }


    }
} catch (Exception e) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution, not the best:

```
    String line=in.nextLine();

    if(line.contains("(1)")) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        line=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        line=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        line=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        line=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like below, minor tweek might be required:

```
int  b = 0;
while(in.hasNext()) {
          String line=in.nextLine();
            if (0<b<6) {
System.out.println(line);
              b++;
            }
            if (b == 6){
              b = 0;}

            if(b==0 && line.contains("(1)")) {
            System.out.println(line);
            b++;
         }

        }
```